# Can i run a C++ Qt Application in Simulink model?

Tags: c++, qt, simulink

My doubt is if I can call a c++ code (that basic is a Qt application) in Simulink? So, it is possible to run the code via s function and simulink will display a Qt Window?

Comment: In principle it [looks like](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/structure-of-c-mex-function.html) you can write arbitrary C++ code in your `matlab::mex::Function` override, so you could e.g. do something with `QString`. However for Qt GUI to be work correctly you need the Qt event loop running, which normally is achieved by calling `QApplication::exec`. Try to do it and let's see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm now, it's totally possible! Just write your code as library, generate the mex file, then call it. It will work!